# Link Sceneform Nodes/Objects to Scale and Move Together

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

If I have two separate Sceneform Transformable Nodes with their own AnchorNodes and Anchors, how do I 'link' them together so that the user's gestures (Pinch and Drag) have the same effect on both of them?
If I assign them on the same Anchor or AnchorNode, that makes their location same but I do not want that, I want the two nodes to maintain their relative position after they are linked.
I know how to scale and rotate a node if I know by how much I need to do that but I cannot figure out a way to reliably listen to the Gesture starting and ending.

Answer (score 2):

In order to transform two different nodes simultaneously you need to assign a `mutual Parent Node` for them. After parenting, your two nodes still maintain their relative position.

Hierarchy must look like that:

[image]

From that moment, all the transformations will be applied to `both Children Nodes`. All the downstream hierarchy of nodes obey a Parent Node's transformation.

You also should look at Google's project called [Solar System](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/Planet.java) at GitHub.